# Dynamic return type based on input argument type

Tags: java, list, guava, return-type

I'm trying to write a small function that takes two lists and sorts one based on the elements of the other. So something like:

```
List<Integer> keys = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 2, 4, 1);
List<String> valuesToSort = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

List<String> sortedValues = sort(keys, valuesToSort);
```

would result in a sorted list `[E, C, A, D, B]`.

However, `valuesToSort` might be a list of something different, like integers, floats or other lists. Ideally, I would want my program to take any list I throw at it, sort it according to `keys`, and then return a list of the same type as the input. How would I do that? If the type of `values` were fixed, the sorting itself would be straightforward, like for example

```
public List<String> sort(List<Integer> keys, List<String> values){
    Multimap<Integer, String>> multiMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        multiMap.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    List<String>> sortedValues = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Integer key : Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(multiMap.keys())) {
        for (String value : multiMap.get(key)) {
            sortedValues.add(value);
        }
    }
return sortedValues;
}
```

but this only works if `values` is a list of the expected type.

Comment: Just use a generic type variable instead of `String`?

Comment: For this you would use [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). But a better design would be to use objects in your list containing the keys. If necessary you can implement a custom Comparator. Two lists are very error-prone, because you have to make sure that they always fit together.

Comment: Maybe a [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) would also fit. Depends on the use case.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That would indeed work in order to successfully sort the values (something like ```List<T> values```), but it would also mean that I return a list of the generic type. Now I could just manually cast the returned list to whatever the initial ```values``` was, but ideally, the returned list would be of the same type as the initial list by default. But I don't know if such a dynamic return type would even be possible, so that might be the best I can get here.

Comment: As a minor aside: `sortedValues.addAll(multiMap.get(key));` replaces the need for the nested for loop.

Comment: Offtopic note: you don't need guava Multimap. Assuming `keys` contain permutation of indices, simple loop suffices: `List<T> sortedValue = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(keys.size(),null)); for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) sortedValues.set(keys.get(i) - 1, valuesToSort.get(i));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Generics for this as follow:

```java
public List<T> sort(List<Integer> keys, List<T> values){
    Multimap<Integer, T>> multiMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        multiMap.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    List<T> sortedValues = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Integer key : Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(multiMap.keys())) {
        for (T value : multiMap.get(key)) {
            sortedValues.add(value);
        }
    }
    return sortedValues;
}
```

Now, when you pass list of strings, the generic `T` would be considered as `String`. When you pass list of integers, `T` would become `Integer`. This will happen at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does work. But now, ```sortedValues``` is also of a generic type. I could obviously just cast it to whatever list type ```values``` originally was, but is there by chance a way to automatically return the correct type?

Comment: @PebNischl, you don't have to cast the `sortedValues`, since it would refer to the same type as `values`.

Comment: You could make it even more generic by declaring a type variable `K extends Comparable<? super K>`, and using that instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.  I am presuming that the keys could have duplicate numbers like `[3, 5, 2, 2, 1]`. Otherwise, simpler algorithms would prevail.

- Sort the values from `0 to keys.size()` using the `keys` list
- for the cited example, this will result in the following stream of integers. `[4 2 0 3 1]`
- then use those to index into the values list.
- this will then yield the desired order.

```
List<Integer> keys = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 2, 4, 1);
List<String> valuesToSort =
        Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

List<String> result = sort(keys, valuesToSort);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[E, C, A, D, B]
```

The generic method

- make it static
- the value list is just indexed so that can be any type `T`
- the key list must be of type `Integer`

```
public static <T> List<T> sort(List<Integer> keys, List<T> values){
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size()).boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(keys::get))
            .map(values::get).toList();
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty simple solution.  Did it work for you?  Or were you looking for something else?

Comment: The project I'm working on is still based on Java 11, so Stream.toList() isn't available. But that issue is obviously on me, and the solution is correct for an up-to-date project, so still +1.

Comment: Replace `toList()` with `collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: BTW,  to help others when they search you may want to update your tags with Guava if this is what you are using.  I did notice some rather interesting classes.  I could have done this myself but I wasn't certain since I don't use it.